# .echo 5+5 displays "5+5" in WinDBG. Is it possible to make it display 10?

Tags: windbg

Please, observe:

```
0:033> .echo 5+5
5+5
0:033> ? 5+5
Evaluate expression: 10 = 00000000`0000000a
0:033> r @$t0=5+5
0:033> r @$t0
$t0=000000000000000a
0:033> .echo @$t0
@$t0
```

`?` is almost what I need, but it is too verbose. Is there a way to invoke `.echo` on an expression, so that it display the result of the expression and not the expression text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.printf` may do the job straight away:

```
0:000> .printf "%d", 5+5
10
```

Of course you can also hack around `.echo` to get it in decimal or even hex:

```
0:000> .foreach /pS 2 /ps 2 (word {? 5+5}) { .echo ${word}}
10
0:000> .foreach /pS 4 (word {? 5+5}) { .echo ${word}}
0000000a
```

The C++ expression evaluation (`??`) output is related, but has type information

```
0:000> ?? 5+5
int 0n10
```

Answer (score 2):

i use a script file like this when i need a plain output

the semicolon is needed or a blank line is needed in the script file 
setting alias cant be the first command in script file

edit [using alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-aliases)

> When a line begins with an as command, aliases and tokens in that line
>   are not expanded. If we put a semicolon or blank space before the as
>   command, then any alias or token that already has a value is expanded.

```
;aS /x temp  ${$arg1} ${$arg2} ${$arg3}
.block
{
    .echo ${temp}
}
ad *
```

and use it like this

```
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 + 5
0xa
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt f + f
0x1e
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt f + 8
0x17
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0n16 + 0n16
0x20
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0x10 + 0x10
0x20
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0x10 * 0x10
0x100
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0n10 * 0n10
0x64
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 << 3
0x28
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 >> 3
0x0
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt f >> 3
0x1
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0y101 + 0y111
0xc
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0y101 % 0y111
0x5
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0y111 % 2
0x1
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0y111 % 4
0x3
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0y111 % 0n10
0x7
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0y111 / 0n10
0x0
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 0n2 / 0n10
0x0
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt @@c++(@$teb->ProcessEnvironmentBlock) + 18
0x7ffd6018
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 & 1
0x1
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 & 2
0x0
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 & 3
0x1
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 & 4
0x4
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 5 & 5
0x5
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt @esp & @esp
0x12f9a4
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt 3 | 4
0x7
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt poi(@esp+c) + 0
0x7ffd6000
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt poi(@esp+c) + @ecx
0x80105988
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt @ecx + 0
0x12f988
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt calc + 3c
0x1d003c
0:000> $$>a< eval.txt poi(calc+3c) + calc 
0x1d00d8
```

Comment: could you please explain regarding the usage of semicolon here?

Comment: msdn docs about using alias has an explanation i edited in a link and quoted the relevent part take a look